# iOS 6.1 animation not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

The following method that i created for animation:

```
-(void)shakingAnimationForGate:(UIImageView *)image leftShaking:(CGAffineTransform)leftTransform rightShaking:(CGAffineTransform)rightTransform animationName:(NSString *)string{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

    image.transform = leftTransform;  // starting point

    [UIView beginAnimations:string context:(__bridge void *)(image)];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:20];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.06];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(shakeEnded:finished:context:)];

    image.transform = rightTransform; // end here & auto-reverse

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            NSLog(@"end of shaking");
    }];

}
```

which makes UIView do the "shaking".

Then i'm using this method:

```
CGAffineTransform leftShake = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-2, 6);
CGAffineTransform rightShake = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 3);

[self shakingAnimationForGate:imageLeft leftShaking:leftShake rightShaking:rightShake animationName:@"left view shake"];
```

where **imageLeft** is **UIImageView**.

So my problem is that this method don't do animation of shaking on iOS 6.1. It's working fine on iOS 7 though. Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: Just do [UIView animate]?

Comment: do you mean commitAnimations? it's already in method that i've created

Comment: I assume you're trying to do an animation which happens 20 times? Which starts point A, animates to point B, then starts all over from point A?

Comment: yup, 20 shakes 0.06 sec each :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling, Xcode optimises your code a little. For example if you execute the following code, only the last line is executed:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Most likely that's the case with the animation as well.

Move the revert part to the completion part.

Comment: thanks, but my animation method working on iOS 7, and there's no problem with  "optimising" code.